# Залил на хостинг, а на странице после футера пишется текст с ошибкой

Tags: apache, hosting

Залил проект (laravel) на хостинг www.networksolutions.com. По адресу mysite.com страница загружается, все хорошо, но переходя на другую страницу mysite.com/eng переходит, отрабатывает, но внизу под футером пишет еще такой вот текст:

```
OK

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, [no address given] and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

Хотя до этого заливал на удаленный тестовый сервер, на моем локальном сервере - все нормально. Подскажите с чем это может быть связано? И как устранить данную ошибку?

Comment: И что же пишут в server error log?

Comment: по поводу этого логи на этом хостинге не появляются.....я настроил , папка с логами пустая....

Comment: Попробуйте поставить в htaccess строку RewriteBase /

Comment: сейчас пробую...

Comment: дописал....ничего не поменялось......логи не появились...

Comment: Что-то тут в настройках хостера или виртуального хоста. Что именно - сказать сложно при отсутствии информации

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если, вдруг, столкнетесь с подобным, не забудьте узнать какой сервер стоит на Вашем хостинге, куда заливаете! Такое бывает, когда код пишет один человек, а на хостинг заливает совершенно другой. Я разворачивал проект на локальном сервере (.htaccess,sk ghjgbcfy gjl  apache 2.4), а на  хостинге,на который заливал, стоит Microsoft IIS. Выводы очевидны!